# Position JQueryAutocomplete Results

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am implementing JQuery Autocomplete in my website, I have problem in displaying results in search form.The search form is embedded in Bootstrap3 navbar in main layout.

```
 inside navbar

 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" id="search">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search" action ="{{ path('search')}}" method ="get">
       <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search city/town" name="query" value="{{ app.request.get('query') }}" id="search_keywords">
       <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

        </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

js

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }
        $( "#search_keywords").autocomplete({
            source: "{{ path('city_autocomplete') }}",
            minLength: 2,
            messages: {
                noResults: '',
                results: function() {}
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.label:
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
                $("#search_keywords").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#search_keywords").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },
            change: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#search_keywords" ).val( ui.item? ui.item.value : 0 );
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want a 'gap' between the search form and the results since results is partly 'hidden' in search form.

[image]

Inside JQuery, I add

```
 position: { my : "bottom+3" },
```

But it doesn't work.
As of the CSS, except for some tables and forms not related to this search form and layout, I relied heavily on bootstrap's cdn, So I have no custom css for this search form.
 Any ideas?

Comment: You should post a complete, working example of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it

```
.ui-autocomplete {
margin-top: 20px !important;
top: 0px !important;
```

}